# grep : Count the number of elements in json response

Tags: json, regex, linux, bash, grep

I am using `grep` command to get the number of elements present in the `json` API response (retrieved by `curl`). Below is an example response:

```
[{"k1":"v1"},{"k2:"v2"}]
```

The above response contains 2 elements so I want the command to return 2. Below is what I have tried:

```
echo '[{"k1":"v1"},{"k2:"v2"}]' | grep -oP '\[{.+}\]' | wc -l
echo '[{"k1":"v1"},{"k2:"v2"}]' | grep -oP '{.+}' | wc -l
echo '[{"k1":"v1"},{"k2:"v2"}]' | grep -oP '\{.+\}' | wc -l
```

All these match the whole string and I just get `1` as an output for each of the above commands. What changes do I need to make in order for `grep` to return the correct count? It needs to be key/value agnostic.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/zfE4nI, you need a non-greedy quantifier, `grep -oP '\{.+?\}'`

Comment: This should not be done via regex as this is JSON data and regex will break with slight change of data. Use `jq` instead.

Comment: `jq '. | length' <<< '[{"k1":"v1"},{"k2":"v2"}]'`

Comment: @anubhava unfortunately I do not have `jq` installed on live servers so can't use it.